# How do I get a callback url?

Tags: facebook-apps, facebook-chatbot, facebook-webhooks, callbackurl

I am creating my first chatbot with Facebook for developers and I don't know how to set a callback url. I already have my url (IP address of my EC2 instance). Do you know by any chance how could I obtain one? And do I have to set a domain name for my app? Thanks a lot in advance!

Comment: what did you try so far?

Comment: I looked at ngrok and I wondered if there were a easiest way to fo it..

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you need a domain name. The Platform won't accept an IP address for a webhook. All you need to do is expose an https endpoint on your EC2 instance that can accept POST requests, and provide that URL.